# Toggle class in li list one by one in using mouseover event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Toggle class in li list one by one in using mouseover event in JavaScript.

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
let selectedEl;

for (const el of list) {
  el.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    selectedEl && selectedEl.classList.remove("active");
    selectedEl = e.target;
    e.target.classList.add("active");
  });
}
```

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.container{
    height:100vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    background-color:#eee;
}

.card{
    height:400px;
    width:330px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0px 15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    overflow:hidden;
}

.card ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    
}
.card ul li{
    position:absolute;
    width:320px;
    height:300px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    display:none;
}

.card ul li.active{
    display:block !important;
}

.card ul li img{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
       <ul id="list-row">
           <li class="active"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/dzyiJS2.jpg"></li>
           <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7BwBYPB.jpg"></li>
           <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/HjkIPFZ.jpg"></li>
       </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I actually want to change the image one by one from the list and add an active class to the list item when I hover over the image. And, it should change after 2-3 seconds of interval. It will be the same as a carousel.

Comment: to get this clear you want the img to start changing after hover every 3 seconds?

Comment: Exactly... want the img to start changing after hover every 3 seconds?

Comment: got u give me a sec

Answer (score 0):

```js
//arr of path of images
const imgArr = ['./imglocation1', 'imglocation2', 'imglocation3', ...]
const imgContainer = document.getElementById("imgCon");

//onHover run changeImg() function
imgContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
  changeImg()
}, false);

function changeImg() {

  //set arrays first path
  imgContainer.src = imgArr[0];

  //wait for 3 sec to change(3000 millisec = 3 sec)
  setTimeout(() => {
    //set arrays second path
    imgContainer.src = imgArr[1];
    //wait another 3 sec
    setTimeout(() => {
      //set arrays third path
      imgContainer.src = imgArr[2];
      //loop changing img again
      changeImg()
    }, 3000)
  }, 3000)

}
```

```css
#imgCon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
}
```

```html
<img id="imgCon" src="" />
```